# Get the position of a tooltip

Tags: wpf, tooltip

How can I Get the position of a tooltip once it has been shown (or just before ?)

I've made a custom control with an arrow and I'd like to set the right position for my arrow depending on the position.
With a converter I'm able to get the tooltip and return the position of my arrow.

But how can I know where the tooltip is placed ? It seems that the placement property is always set at Top (but in my example the tooltip is under my button ...)

I've tried this : (tried to bind the whole Tooltip or only the Placement Property. Placement is always "Top".

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is PlacementMode)
            {
                PlacementMode pm = (PlacementMode)value;
                TooltipArrowPosition retour = TooltipArrowPosition.Top;
                switch (pm)
                {
                    case PlacementMode.Top:
                        retour = TooltipArrowPosition.Bottom;
                        break;
                    case PlacementMode.Bottom:
                        retour = TooltipArrowPosition.Top;
                        break;

                }
                return retour;
            }
            else if (value is ToolTip)
            {
                ToolTip tt = (ToolTip)value;
            }
            return TooltipWithArrow.TooltipArrowPosition.Top;
        }
```

**EDIT** : My template had a setter on "placement" which was set to Top, I removed it and it is set on "Mouse" now, That's not really helping me on this problem.
But I "need" it to top, I want my tooltips on the top of buttons/datagrid by default and under under the control if there isn't enough space.

**EDIT2** 
I'm trying to get the absolute position of my tooltip and compare it to the absolute position of the button, I can get the position of the button but I can't find the ancestor of the tooltip to get its relative position, have you any idea ?

```
else if (value is ToolTip)
            {
                ToolTip tt = (ToolTip)value;
                PlacementMode pm = tt.Placement;
                if (tt.Parent is Popup)
                {
                    Popup pp = (Popup)tt.Parent;


                        Point relativePoint = pp.PlacementTarget.TransformToAncestor(MainWindow._This.TopGrid)
                              .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
                        Point relativePointPopup = tt.TransformToAncestor(???)
                              .Transform(new Point(0, 0));

                }
            }
```